# Difference between "Introduction" and "Background summary" in report writing

Tags: meaning, differences

I have a task to do: writing a report. This one needs to be 4 pages as directed by the assigner. I was told to write 1/4, 3/4, 2 and 1/4 pages of **Introduction**, **Background Summary**, **Discussion** and **Conclusion** respectively.

I find these two - Introduction and Background Summary - to be similar. What is the difference between these two? Can anyone direct me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An introduction is the teaser for your background summary.  It is meant to be short and attention grabbing, and make the reader actually want to read further into the background summary.

A background summary goes in depth, while a introduction does just that... introduce the reader to what will come.

## Example

### Intro

Known worldwide for it's magnificient Eiffel Tower, France has so much more to offer in magnificence.

### Background

France is a European country situated between England and Spain.  The dominant language is, of course, French.  The country also borders the Pyrenees Mountains to the southwest, and Italy to the southeast.

Comment: As an example, we can say, Introduction is like Continent while Background Summary is like Country?

Comment: An introduction is more like, a historical landmark or interesting fact about a country, while the background summary would be the country.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure if a post here gets as much attention as in stackoverflow. Should I wait for someone else's response to your answer or just accept it? I am sorry if this question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: updated with example

Comment: No words to thank you. It is quite clear to me now.